# How to use Laravel Passport to secure multiple users and external apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, passport.js, laravel-passport, laravel-9

I want to use my Laravel Passport and Breeze app to authenticate a pure standalone PHP app, a node API, and another database system using OAuth2.

Multiple users will use these apps, and I would like to create an SSO, so they don't have to connect on each or manually enter client id and secret.

I tried the PHP League OAuth Client https://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/usage/ and the passport.js, and everything works fine with the Laravel Passport app I have to enter the client ID and the secret manually. So I want to find a connecting flow so that users don't have to do so.

Which flow would you suggest to me? Do you have any examples I could learn from?

Comment: As the name says, a `client_id` and `client_secret` are for the `client`, not the user.

Comment: But what I understand the client is set on a specific user. Am I wrong? Can many users can use the same client_id/secret?

Comment: The application is the Client, a user is the resource owner. Try to use [the correct terminology](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/terminology/).